# How can I repeat playing a media file with use of class "MediaPlayer" in Android for several times (for example n times)?

Tags: android

I have the code for playing a media file for one time like the following:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
mp.start();
```

But how can I repeat playing the media file for several times (for example n times)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach an `OnCompletionListener`, decrement a counter and start the media player again, playing the same file.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

You have to start the `MediaPlayer` item and than add the `onCompletionListener` which is called for each iteration's finish.

than, `start()` it again the needed number of times doing like the following:

```
int numberOfReplay = 10;
int currentReplay = 0;

MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);

mp.start();
currentReplay++;

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if( currentReplay < numberOfReplay){
            mp.start();
            currentReplay++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code does not work

Comment: @FarnadTohidkhah which error comes out?

Comment: it does not play anything

Comment: @FarnadTohidkhah I edited, anyway u know that you have to set your own song's name right? R.raw.song is a sample

Comment: There are some errors in the code

Comment: after editing the code it goes to infinite repeatation

Comment: If you never post code or errors noone will help you, so please do it. "There are some errors in the code" means nothing for someone having no enviroment with him

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88067/discussion-between-farnad-tohidkhah-and-pier-giorgio-misley).

Comment: errors can resolved, logic is ok.